# Platform specific deserialisation in golang?

Tags: rest, go, amazon-ec2, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am hitting a REST API and getting some data back. I came across an interesting behaviour yesterday. I haven't understood the exact reasoning behind the it yet. Which is what I'm trying to seek here.
For a payload that looks like -

```
{
    "id": 2091967,
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "email": "",
    "telephone": "",
    "timezone": "",
    "weekly_capacity": "",
    "has_access_to_all_future_projects": false,
    "is_contractor": false,
    "is_admin": false,
    "is_project_manager": false,
    "can_see_rates": false,
    "can_create_projects": false,
    "can_create_invoices": false,
    "is_active": false,
    "created_at": "2018-04-16T00:48:30Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-11-07T22:47:43Z",
    "default_hourly_rate": null,
    "cost_rate": null,
    "roles": [
        "blah"
    ],
    "avatar_url": ""
}
```

I used a function like below to get the email -

```
func GetUserEmail(userID int) string {
    resp := getFromSomething("https://something/users/" + strconv.Itoa(userID))
    var result map[string]string

    json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result)
    log.Printf("userEmail: %s", result["email"])
    return result["email"]
}
```

The code worked perfectly on my mac where I was building it like - `env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/something cmd/main.go`
But, it failed to deserialize, and didn't print anything on an EC2 instance when using the same build command.

But then, I changed the `var result map[string]string` to `var result map[string]interface{}`  and it worked on both my EC2 instance and mac.

I also had to typecast the `interface{}` object at the end before returning it.

```
func GetUserEmail(userID int) string {
    resp := getFromSomething("https://something/users/" + strconv.Itoa(userID))
    var result map[string]interface{}

    json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result)
    log.Printf("userEmail: %s", result["email"])
    return result["email"].(string)
}
```

**Has anyone seen things like this before? Or, does anyone know why this happened?**

I understand that the payload can always be represented better by `var result map[string]interface{}`, **but my question is - why did that earlier representation of `var result map[string]string` work on the Mac and not on EC2?**

Go version on Mac - `go version go1.11.2 darwin/amd64` and that on EC2 is `go version go1.10.3 linux/amd64`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always check for and handle errors.

The error returned from Decode explains the problem.  The application is attempting to decode numbers, booleans and arrays to string values.

```
var v map[string]string
err := json.NewDecoder(data).Decode(&v) // data is the JSON document from the question
fmt.Println(err)  // prints json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7aRws2DMosQ).

This issue is not platform specific. I have a couple of guesses why you saw different results:

- Different JSON documents were used when testing on the different platforms.
- The question states that the command `env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o bin/something cmd/main.go` was used to build the Mac version, but this command does not build a binary that's executable on the Mac.  Perhaps you were not running the code you thought you were running.

Either decode to `map[string]interface{}` as you discovered or decode to a struct with the one field you want:

```
var v struct{ Email string }
if err := json.NewDecoder(data).Decode(&v); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
fmt.Println(v.Email) // prints the decoded email value.
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0oAPJfgOoEN).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Oh, I didn't know I could deserialise it into just the field I wanted! Sort of like an overloaded constructor with `@JsonCreator` using just one field from the Java world. 

I do have a struct with all the fields in it even though I need just one. 
Will catch the err as you mentioned. 
And, no, I was getting the same payload back regardless of where I ran it.

Comment: Given that the JSON document in the question cannot be decoded to `map[string]string` on any platform and the same JSON document was used on all platforms, something else was amiss when this application was tested.

Comment: There is no platform specific code in the JSON decoder.  Can you reproduce it now (successfully decoding the document)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it anymore. :-( Wonder what happened then!
Nevertheless, thank you for your help.